# Set the Y-axis min value for kendo line chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, kendo-chart

I wish to set the min value for my y-Axis to be `10 less than the lowest value in the Y-axis)`.[Like if Min value is 83.33 (on Y-axis) so I want min value set to 73.33]

```
.ValueAxis(axis => axis
.Numeric()
.Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}"))
.AxisCrossingValue(-10)
.Line(line => line.Visible(false))
.Color("White").Min(MinValueOf Y-axis -10)
```

Or at least .Min(MinValueOf Y-axis)

I was able to solve this....

```
$("#IndexChart").data("kendoChart").dataSource.read();

                //get reference to the chart widget
                var chart = $("#IndexChart").data("kendoChart");
                chart.bind("dataBound", function (e) {
                    var data = e.sender.dataSource.view(); 
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));

                    var allVals = [];//get all Y Axis data...
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        allVals.push(data[i].DuplicatePrice);
                        allVals.push(data[i].OriginalPrice);
                    }

                    var least = Math.min.apply(Math, allVals); //get the least value
                    e.sender.options.valueAxis.min = least - 10; //set the least-10 as min
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Suk's answer, if you're grouping your data, the view method returns an array of groups. For each element in this array, access the items array to get the data for the current group.

```
    // get filtered (and grouped) data
    var grpData = chart.dataSource.view();
    var allVals = [];

    // loop through all the groups in the view
    for (var grp = 0; grp < grpData.length; grp++) {
        // loop through data in each group
        for (var i = 0; i < grpData[grp].items.length; i++) {
            allVals.push(grpData[grp].items[i].DuplicatePrice);
            allVals.push(grpData[grp].items[i].OriginalPrice);
        }
    }
```